# Edit event color using Python and Google API

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api

I want to edit the color of an individual event as I insert it into a Google Calendar using Python to interact with the Google API.  I'm using the dictionary below to compose the event itself, and I thought that colorId was a part of the event, but I feel like I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how to use to use it.

```
event = {
            "summary": name,
            "colorId": "Tangerine",
            "start": {
                "date": ymd,
                },
            "end": {
                "date": ymd,
                },
            "recurrence": [
                "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;COUNT=100",
                ],
            }
event = service.events().insert(calendarId="id number of calendar goes here", body=event).execute()
```

However, I don't really know how to go about fixing this.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, cripes.  Answer is straightforward.  The dictionary is properly formatted as it stands, but the input under "colorId" should be a numeric string (e.g., "6", etc.).  Reference can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/ztjga41q/

```
event = {
        "summary": name,
        "colorId": "6",
        "start": {
            "date": ymd,
            },
        "end": {
            "date": ymd,
            },
        "recurrence": [
            "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;COUNT=100",
            ],
        }
```